# Count how many cells up until the text changes from buy to sell or sell to buy

Tags: count, match, offset

So I am tracking the close of a stock. Based on some calculations I get a buy, hold or sell signal. Part of the calculation requires finding a range from the last time the order changed from buy to sell or sell to buy. That range is then checked for the max or min to determine the next buy, sell, or hold order. If yesterday was a buy or hold after a buy, I need it to count up cells from the bottom until it discovers a sell order and check the close for the Max in that range. If yesterday was a sell or hold after a sell it needs to look for the buy to check the Min in that range. I believe there must be a way to use match() and offset() but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't want to do this with VBA.

Comment: Here is a worksheet I am working on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1smra40OIRkZiavUjMMCPuE3T-voDtu7jMP4wiOxOd-w/edit#gid=1142316995

Comment: Did Covid-19 make this site shut down? Usually I have an answer the same day...